# Optimize cost of workers

Tags: optimization, nonlinear-optimization, discrete-optimization

We have a warehouse at which a number of trucks arrive. We have the time of arrival and departure of each truck and the amount of worker-hour(s) it takes to load/unload each truck. So for e.g, a truck can arrive at 10 AM and leave at 1 AM and requires a total of 6 worker-hours to load/unload. So we would need 2 workers working for the three hours, or 3 workers working two hours within that window or any suitable combination to load/unload.

Now if we have shifts defined for workers, let's say 9AM-5PM and 5PM-12AM and when we hire a worker we hire them for the whole shift and have to pay even if they sit idly during that. So for the given inputs above, how do we minimize the cost(worker-hours) while ensuring that all the trucks are loaded/unloaded within the time it is available at the warehouse.

Now, I know that this is not an easy optimization problem with a clear, closed form solution. But I am unable to even approach this problem. So if anyone could guide on how to approach this problem and what class of optimization problems this belongs to, it'd be great.

Assumptions:

1. Truck times are arbitrary. There can be overlap between the time trucks are at the warehouse and there could also be times when no truck is there.
2. Any reasonable assumption that I might've missed.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: There is not enough information available to admit any answer. Do you know when the trucks will arrive and depart in advance? If it happens that a large group of trucks are going to overlap a given time, can you always hire enough workers to cover that shift in advance? Without that, there is no way to ensure you can always unload/reload the trucks. If you can do that, the problem is simple. You simply have to figure out for each shift how many workers are required for the trucks arriving and hire them.

Comment: Yes we do know the time of arrival and departure of the trucks in advance and also we are able to hire as much workers needed. But even in that case it does not seem simple to optimise for workers.